# How to make only one instance of application to be used by multiple users?

Tags: java

This is not about restricting opening multiple instances. I wrote a little app that creates reports and send scheduled emails. This app is on a common drive folder that everybody in our company has access to.

I want to set it up the way so that it would really execute only from my computer (like a server). However, all other people could open it and see all the processes that are going on at the instance that is open on my computer and could also make modifications etc

How can I do it?

Comment: Your task is not clear. Try to explain it better.

Comment: just an idea - store the ip address of the computer that can do everything in an ini file on the shared drive and then if the computer running the app does not match the IP, then it acts as read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single copy of an app running on a server and handling requests from multiple locations... that's called "client-server" and you have essentially two choices:

- A modern HTML-based web application (aka "thin client", but the "thin" part is debatable nowadays).  The user interface is implemented in HTML/Javascript/CSS, runs on the client's browser, and interacts with a web server over the network (HTTP or AJAX or both) to execute the application logic.  The main advantage of this is that the client needs only a modern web browser and can be run on any platform that supports the browser (Windows, Linux, iOS, MacOS, etc)
- A "fat client" application. You write the user interface using Java/Swing/AWT/GWT/etc, and a server component also using Java. They communicate over the network using whatever you want to layer on top of TCP/IP. This can also run on many clients but they must have Java installed, so iOS is probably out.  And clients may need to install Java, and some users may not want to.  I.e. some clients might encounter a barrier to running your app.

A detailed explanation of how to write client-server apps is far beyond the scope of SO.  You'll need to do a lot of reading and studying.